# Base point free $D$ implies existence of rational map with fiber $D$ over finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$ the projective line over the field. Let $D$ be any effective divisor of degree $d$.

Q: Can I always find a morphism $f: C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$ such that the fiber of $0$ is equal to $D$, if $D$ is base point free? If not, if $\deg D$ is greater than some other value?

It is clear to me that if $d \geq 2g$ then our divisor $D$ is base-point free. If this was a curve over an algebraically closed field this would solve our problem, because then $L(D) \supsetneq \cup_{P \in D} L(D - P)$ as the former is a vector space of dimension $d + 1 - g$, and the (finite) union is over subspaces of dimension $d - g$. So we can find an $f$ with the right fiber.

However, because our curve is over a finite field, these will be finite vector fields, which have the property that they can be covered by subspaces of lower dimension. Is the base-point freeness of $D$ still enough to ensure the existence of such an $f$?

Even a reference to anything that might help, would greatly help me (I'm having trouble googling this)

Comment: If Riemann-Roch theorem works, then we have $h^0(D) = 2$ if $\deg(D) \geq \frac{3g - 1}{2}$ (if I didn't made a mistake but surely I did). For such $d$, this means that there is $E$ effective and a rational function $g$ with $\text{div}(g) + D = E$, which means that $\text{div}(g) = E - D$, i.e the fiber over $\infty$ is exactly $D$, and you can take $f = 1/g$.

Comment: @N.H. I had thought of that, but consider: 
What if the fiber of $g$ above $\infty$ is not *exactly* $D$, but just a (lower degree) divisor, i.e. $D - S$ for some effective $S$ of degree between $0$ and $d$?

Comment: This can always be done, if $D$ is basepoint free, in particular for all large degrees (certainly if $\deg D>2g$).

Comment: @Krijn if $\text{div}(g) = E - D$ with $E,D$ effective then the poles of $g$ is exactly $D$ right ?

Comment: @N.H. I might be misunderstanding this then. Say we have four points $X, Y, Z$ and $W$ on $C$. If $D = X + Y$ and $g$ has divisor $Z - X$ we would get $(g) + D = Z + Y$, so $E = Z + Y$ and indeed wou would have $(g) = E - D$ but $g$ does not have the right degree $d = \deg D$

Comment: You are right, and this is probably why we need the hypothesis "$D$ is basepoint free" : this means that for all $p \in X$ there is $D' \sim D$ with $D'(p) = 0$, and here your counter-example doesn't work. ($D$ basepoint free implies that for any finite set $F$ there is a divisor $D' \sim D$ with $D'(p) = 0 \forall p \in F$).

Comment: But then, I would argue that the $f$ we are looking for exists as $l(D - P) = l(D) - 1$ for all $P$ in $D$ and we normally use that you cannot get $L(D)$ as a finite union of lower dimensional vector spaces. However, doesn't this argument fail here, as $L(D)$ is a vector space of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ (I believe my $l(D)$ is your $h^0(D)$, right?)